Can't make uberjar with deps.edn and build.clj
It seems to compile it just fine, but when I try to run it I get
Error: Could not find or load main class _main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: _main
I've boiled it down to these files:
helloearth.clj
(ns helloearth
    (:gen-class))

(defn -main
    [& args]
    (println "Hello Earth"))

deps.edn
{; project paths
 :paths ["src"]

 :deps {
        org.clojure/clojure {:mvn/version "1.12.0"}
        }
 :aliases {
           ;; Run with clj -T:build function-in-build
           :build {:deps {io.github.clojure/tools.build {:git/tag "v0.10.6" :git/sha "52cf7d6"}}
                   :ns-default build}
           }}


build.clj
(ns build
    (:require [clojure.tools.build.api :as b]))

(def lib 'helloearth/helloearth)
(def version (format "1.2.70"))
(def class-dir "target/classes")
(def uber-file (format "target/%s-%s-standalone.jar" (name lib) version))

;; delay to defer side effects (artifact downloads)
(def basis (delay (b/create-basis {:project "deps.edn"})))

(defn clean [_]
      (b/delete {:path "target"}))

(defn uber [_]
      (clean nil)
      (b/copy-dir {:src-dirs ["src"]
                   :target-dir class-dir})
      (b/write-pom {:class-dir class-dir
                    :lib       lib
                    :version   "1.0.0"
                    :basis     basis
                    :src-dirs  (:paths basis)})
      (b/compile-clj {:basis @basis
                      ;:ns-compile '[clock2.main]
                      :src-dirs (:paths basis)
                      :class-dir class-dir})
      (b/uber {:class-dir class-dir
               :uber-file uber-file
               :basis basis
               :main '-main}))


What have I missed?

@amalloy is correct about :main but it should be a symbol so :main 'helloearth and, in addition, you have several references to basis that should be @basis since you are using a delay.
Having a single-segment namespace can be problematic (because of Java package name issues) so that's something else to consider.
Something that might really help you in creating well-structured library and application projects for deps.edn / build.clj projects is deps-new: https://github.com/seancorfield/deps-new
This will let you run commands like:
clojure -Tnew app :name hello/earth

and it'll create a fully-fleshed hello/earth project with src/hello/earth.clj and a working build.clj file etc.

-main is just the name of a function. You could have loads of functions named -main in your jar, up to one per namespace. The point of the :main key is to specify the Main-Class attribute of the manifest in your jar file, so that java knows how to run your program. So you have to specify a class name, not a function name. It's been a while since I did this so I'm not 100% on the details, but I think since you're using gen-class this is the same as the name of your main namespace, i.e."helloearth".
